# SQL query to rows to columns

Tags: sql

I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE #CurrencyRate
(
     [Base] nvarchar(10), 
     [Quote] nvarchar(10), 
     [Amount] nvarchar(10)
)
```

and it has data like this

```
Base   Quote   Amount
---------------------
R1C1   R1C2    R1C3
R2C1   R2C2    R2C3
```

**Note**: `R1C1` => Row 1, Column 1

I want output like

```
Row      Column    Attribute   Value
-----------------------------------------
1          1       Base        R1C1
1          2       Quote       R1C2
1          3       Amount      R1C3
2          1       Quote       R2C1
2          2       Amount      R2C2
2          3       Base        R2C3
```

Is it possible to get output like this with some SQL?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, it is called an UNPIVOT, and if you google that term you will find many examples.

Comment: Looks like SQL server is it? if so what edition? and what determines the "Order" of the rows? base, quote then amount or what?

Comment: The datum 'R1C1' isn't literally 'R1C1', is it?

Answer (score 1):

Unpivot may be simpler, but you also need to generate your row numbers and column numbers somehow...  I did this using a window function but was unsure about the Order of the rows in your table.

But if you're only dealing with 3 columns this should work as well.

```
WITH cte as (
SELECT row_number() 
  over (partition by base,quote,amount order by base, quote Amount) as RN,
Base, Quote, Amount
FROM #CurrencyRate)

SELECT RN as Row, 1 as Column, 'Base', base as value FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT RN, 2, 'Quote', quote FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT RN, 3, 'Amount', Amount FROM cte
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select  
    Row,
    row_number() over (partition by row order by Row) Col,
    Value,
    Attribute
from (
    select Base, Quote, Amount,
    row_number() over (order by Base) Row
    from #CurrencyRate c
) a
unpivot
(
    Value for Attribute in ([Base], [Quote], [Amount])
) unpvt;
```